# Add spacing between columns in Bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, thumbnails

I have the following code

`<% include partials/header %>`

```
<div class="container">

    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp!</h1>

            <p>View our handpicked campgrounds from all over the world!</p>

            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campsite</a></p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="row text-center" >
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-thumbnail p-0 ">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<%= campground.image %>">
                <caption> <%= campground.name %> </caption>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>

<a href="/">Back</a>
</div>


<% include partials/footer %>
```

I'm reading from a campgrounds list and adding them to a Bootstrap grid.
However, the elements have no spacing between them. In Bootstrap 3 those gaps were automatic when using thumbnail (not available in 4). 
If I add a margin `mx-3`, for example, to

```
`class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-thumbnail"`
```

this is added to the total width and the lest item is displaced.
How can I add spacing between columns?

Comment: Use a margin on the image instead, and why do you have `p-0` on the columns? This will remove the spacing between columns.

Comment: use margin-left or margin-right or col-lg-offset-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 can also give you automatic spacing. Assuming you use the right components for your needs.

The right component in your case would be the `figure` component. With the classes `figure-img img-thumbnail` applied to the images.

And for image captions, you should use these (instead of what you tried to use):

```
<figcaption class="figure-caption">Your Image Caption</figcaption>
```

The `justify-content-center` class on the row will center the thumbnails if you happen to have an uneven number of them or if you decide to add `col-md-4` to the columns.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
   <header class="jumbotron pl-5">
       <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp!</h1>
       <p>View our handpicked campgrounds from all over the world!</p>
       <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campsite</a></p>
   </header>

   <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
       <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
           <figure class="figure">
               <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/400/animals" class="figure-img img-thumbnail">
               <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
           </figure>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
           <figure class="figure">
               <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/400/people" class="figure-img img-thumbnail">
               <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
           </figure>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
           <figure class="figure">
               <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/400/tech" class="figure-img img-thumbnail">
               <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
           </figure>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
           <figure class="figure">
               <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/400/arch" class="figure-img img-thumbnail">
               <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
           </figure>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also: You should avoid nesting Bootstrap containers unless absolutely necessary **which is almost never the case**.

Comment: Yes, using figure is great, but in the end, the `p-0` on the columns was removing the gutter