# How to add space between columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following container with 3 columns using Bootstrap 4

```
  <section id="features">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 ">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" >
          <i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
          <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image: Three columns]

I want to add space between them so they are more separated, however when i try to add padding or margin it breaks the row. How can i add the space maitaining the three items in the same row.

Comment: Hope this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912116/add-spacing-between-columns-in-bootstrap-4-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paddings inside cols works fine. Use class `px-5`. You can use number form 0 to 5 in it. `px` means "padding x" (both left and right). Although you can use size breakpoints in it, like `px-sm-3`. More about padding in Bootstrap 4 here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <section id="features">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 px-5">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 px-5" >
          <i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 px-5">
          <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to manage rows (and columns) of stuffs: it also provides methods to define inner and outer space of elements.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO. Please provide a full solution.